# Is there a onclick function that will give me a idea of how to display an image after searching it in a sql server?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a web application where I need to be able to search a database by ID and the image that is stored on that ID is showed in a preview box. I'm not sure how to get the image to preview somewhere else on the page. I was thinking it would be a onclick event.

I'm using Sql server and I'm new to using sql server for web applications.

Comment: You can add attributes and using that attribute you can get the id of the image and with `onclick` function you can get the attribute and show the image.

Answer (score 0):

When using SQL server you need a server side application, which cannot be done alone with JavaScript. You can make an AJAX call to your server which can return the image in Base64 form where then you can change the `src` of your image.